# Specify url parameters in ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack, ngresource

I have a service using ngResource that I use to access comments for specific news posts in my webapp.

My problem is that when I want to query comments for a specific news post, like this `article.comments = commentService.query()`
The get request is made to `/api/news/comments`, insteaf of `/api/news/:id/comments`. How can I specify the :id so that the get request is sent to the right url(`/api/news/:id/comments`)?

commentService

```
   .factory('commentService', function($resource){
        return $resource('/api/news/:id/comments/:comment', {id: '@news', comment: '@comment'}, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        }, {
            stripTrailingSlashes: false
        }
    )})
```

mehtod for fetching comments on ng-click

```
$scope.getComments = function(article) {
    article.comments = commentService.query()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
$scope.getComments = function(article) {
    return commentService.query({id:article._id})
}
```